WordPress issue: some pages are 404ing
I tried:

Looking at all the server configs (.htaccess, Apache, function files)
Disabling Plugins
Looked for all possible database issues
With help of Query Monitor, tried to identify the cause, the Queries are all being made and returning the expected results.
Renaming the page title, slug and even changing category.

But 404. Here are some URL examples:
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/skin-deep/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/grin-and-bare-it/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/blown-away/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/perfectly-shaped/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/11-fun-ways-to-get-fit-in-dallas/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/time-in-a-bottle/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/jealous-much/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-beauty/2005/beauty-at-any-age/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/1990/may/preludeto-a-masterpiece/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/1999/november/the-bottomline/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/1996/june/home-design-one-great-room-home-for-the-range/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/1998/march/home-design-home-is-where-the-art-is/
https://www.dmagazine.com/food-drink/2015/09/dîner-en-blanc-dallas/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/1997/july/home-design-the-biggest-mistakes-in-bathroom-remodeling/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-home/2015/september-october/best-of-big-d-home-and-garden-edition/
https://www.dmagazine.com/assets/forms/2019-young-leaders-network-sign-up-50-of/
https://www.dmagazine.com/assets/forms/2019-young-leaders-sign-up-comped/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/1997/june/home-design-greenhouse-effect/
https://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/1987/december/1987christmas-calenda/

The rest of the website loads good.

Did you flush the permalinks?

Yes, tried to switch to the standard, and some other configs too, and nothing.

First of rename your existing .htaccess
to some thing like .htaccess_backup
Then go to your permalink
Change to default save.
And again change it back to what your are using now and save again
Check this out on changing permalinks
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

Well... I tried it all again because you asked, but still nothing. Thanks anyway. I think that the standard solutions will not work in this case.

is the .htaccess getting generated after you are changing permalinks.
If not you have permission issue on your server
